# How to do custom sorting using unix sort?

Tags: unix, sorting

I'm using unix sort to sort a comma delimited file with multiple columns. Thus far, this has worked perfectly for sorting the data either numerically or in alphabetical order:

Example file before any sorting:

```
C,United States,WA,Tacoma,f,1
A,United States,MA,Boston,f,0
B,United States,NY,New York,f,5
A,Canada,QC,Montreal,f,2
A,Bahamas,Bahamas,Nassau,f,2
A,United States,NY,New York,f,1
```

Sort the file:  `$ sort -t ',' -k 2,2 -k 3,3 -k 4,4 -k 5,5r -k 6,6nr tmp.csv`

Sorted result:

```
A,Bahamas,Bahamas,Nassau,f,2
A,Canada,QC,Montreal,f,2
A,United States,MA,Boston,f,0
B,United States,NY,New York,f,5
A,United States,NY,New York,f,1
C,United States,WA,Tacoma,f,1
```

**Here is the issue: I want to sort column 2 based on a custom sort, meaning I want United States first, then Canada, then Bahamas:**

Desired sort:

```
A,United States,MA,Boston,f,0
B,United States,NY,New York,f,5
A,United States,NY,New York,f,1
C,United States,WA,Tacoma,f,1
A,Canada,QC,Montreal,f,2
A,Bahamas,Bahamas,Nassau,f,2
```

Is there some way to pass unix sort a custom sort order that it can then apply? Something like: 
`$ sort -t ',' -k 2,2:'United States, Canada, Bahamas' -k 3,3 -k 4,4 -k 5,5r -k 6,6nr tmp.csv`

Thanks!

Comment: For these three values, you want reverse alphabetic order.  For the general case, you'll need to map the names to a sort order number, and then do the sorting using the sort order number.  Or go for a scripting language...  One possibility is the `join` command, but you could end up with a lot of sorting — the input files for `join` must be sorted in one order, and then you'd be using `sort` again to put the data into a different order (and losing the sort order column as a post-sort step).

Comment: In your example input, shouldn't there be `t` instead of `f` in the last line?

Comment: Lev: yes, good catch. My bad; too much cutting and pasting (my actual data set is much larger and I accidentally grabbed the wrong rows).

Comment: I updated the answer to match your data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other answer and comment answer the question in general, here's how an implementation can look like:

```
$ cat order
Bahamas,3
Canada,2
United States,1

$ cat data
C,United States,WA,Tacoma,f,1
A,United States,MA,Boston,f,0
B,United States,NY,New York,f,5
A,Canada,QC,Montreal,f,2
A,Bahamas,Bahamas,Nassau,f,2
A,United States,NY,New York,f,1

$ sort -t, -k2 data | join -t, -11 -22 order - | sort -t, -k2n -k4,5 -k6r -k7nr | cut -d, -f 3,1,4-7
A,United States,MA,Boston,f,0
B,United States,NY,New York,f,5
A,United States,NY,New York,f,1
C,United States,WA,Tacoma,f,1
A,Canada,QC,Montreal,f,2
A,Bahamas,Bahamas,Nassau,f,2
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help. This worked perfectly!

Comment: @jewelia Improved once more, `sed` was not really needed here.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with **sort**.  At this point, you really should be reaching for **awk/perl/your-language-of-choice**.  You can fudge it, though.  You could, for example, use sed to change "United States" to 0, "Canada" to 1 and "Bahamas" to 2, then do a numeric sort against that column, then sed it back.  Or change "United States" to "United States,0" etc, sort against the extra column and then discard it.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote [a helper called csort](https://github.com/aspiers/shell-env/blob/master/bin/csort) to make it easy to do this.  It prefixes each line with a value of your choosing based on substring or regular expression matches within the line:

```
$ csort -t, '2=United States' X 2=Canada Y 2=Bahamas Z < tmp.csv | \
sort -t, -k1,1 -k3,3 -k4,4 -k5,5 -k6,6r -k7,7nr
X,A,United States,MA,Boston,f,0
X,B,United States,NY,New York,f,5
X,A,United States,NY,New York,f,1
X,C,United States,WA,Tacoma,f,1
Y,A,Canada,QC,Montreal,f,2
Z,A,Bahamas,Bahamas,Nassau,f,2
```

The `2=STR` notation means "match if the second field equals `STR`".

You can then optionally pipe the output through `cut -c3-` to remove the prefix.